# Is there a way to print an error message when you try to print a variable?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

For example:

```
CL-USER 1 > (setq l1 '(a b c))
(A B C)

CL-USER 2 > l1
(A B C)
```

When I type ***l1***, instead of ***(A B C)*** I want to print a different message, is that possible? Because is not a manipulation of a function, where I put a condition and instead of the list I print a message.. In this case there's no function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Symbol macros](http://l1sp.org/cl/define-symbol-macro) are a way to evaluate arbitrary code rather than lookup a value when evaluated. For example:

```
* (define-symbol-macro l1 (error "No peeking!"))
* l1
ERROR: No peeking!
```